# Can't get img source inside custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive where i want to get my img src, which comes from a scope variable. Then i'll check this img size and also screen size to either keep this image or change it's source.

But i'm not able to even get the image source at first place, this is my directive:

```
function repSrc($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //Get image source here
            console.log(attrs.repSrc);
        }
    }
}
```

And my html:

```
<li ng-repeat="obj in vm.imageList">
    <img rep-src="{{obj.imgDetail}}" />
</li>
```

I even tried to use the directive inside a controller, tried to change the scope value from `scope: true` to:

```
scope: {
    localImg: '@repSrc'
}
```

But all of them gives me an empty string on the `attrs` value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can access the data with `scope.localImg`. Did you try that with your second scope definition?

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach yes, but still get only an empty string. Even if i do that within a $timeout

Comment: You don't need to use `setTimeout`, but check if `obj.imgDetail` is defined before directive link method is called.

Comment: I think that was the problem, it came from another module, I'm trying to change it now

Comment: Fast test is `<img rep-src="{test:2}">`

Answer (score 0):

Your directive should work fine ([here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/2wLu86g7/)). I think that `obj.imgDetail` is simply empty.